# Question about isKindOfClass

Tags: objective-c

Please look at this code snipped

```
- (SoapRequest*)AddFlyData:(id)_target 
                    action:(SEL)_action 
                 sessionid:(int)sessionid 
                  datasets:(FlyNetArrayOfDataSet*)datasets
{
    if ([datasets isKindOfClass:[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Yeah");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not Yeah");
    }
}
```

Why, when i look on my console, I get

```
2011-09-06 23:08:00.917 soap-test[2133:207] Not Yeah
```

I'm a beginner and I'm completely confused .. :s When I look in the Debugger, the variable type is SoapArray (who is the parent class of FlyNetArrayOfDataSet).

I used a method from SoapArray to initiate my instance of 'datasets', that means the class is automatically defined as Soap and not as FlyNetArrayOfDataSet ?!

Thank you

EDIT: I made a mistake, it's not NSArray but it inherits from SoapArray

This is the header file of the class FlyNetArrayOfDataSet

```
#import "Soap.h"

@interface FlyNetArrayOfDataSet : SoapArray
{
}

+ (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSArray*) array;

@end
```

But that didn't explain me why isKindOfClass returns false ..

EDIT2: Ok I have the response of my question..

I used this method to initialize my instance

```
FlyNetArrayOfDataSet * arr = [FlyNetArrayOfDataSet arrayWithObject:data];
```

This is a static method of the superclass SoapArray that create an instance of SoapArray (Helper) .. but not an instance of FlyNetArrayOfDataSet (!)

Look at its implementation :

```
+ (id)arrayWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...{
    SoapArray* a = [SoapArray array];
    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (firstObj) {
        [a.items addObject: firstObj];
        va_start(argumentList, firstObj);
        while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) {
            [a.items addObject: eachObject];
        }
        va_end(argumentList);
    }
    return a;
}
```

If I initialize my instance like this

```
FlyNetArrayOfDataSet * arr = [[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet alloc] init];
```

It's work perfectly and the method isKindOfClass return true :-)

Comment: With parent class, do you mean the object's class, or the superclass? You should not subclass NSArray.

Comment: Given an example where you call this method. Just because the method wants a certain type of object doesn't mean that's the type you've given it.

Comment: What WTP says is right, never ever subclass from a class cluster. It results in pain and unstable software.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a class named "FlyNetArrayOfDataSet" which inherits from (=is a subclass of) NSArray.

If you instantiate a variable like:

```
FlyNetArrayOfDataSet *arr = [[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet alloc] init];
```

As you can see, I'm initializing the array with a method of NSArray. However, my "arr" object will be of kind FlyNetArrayOfDataSet, and NOT NSArray, because I called the FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class (see `[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet arrayWithObject....`).

```
NSLog(@"%d", [arr isKindOfClass:[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class]]);
NSLog(@"%d", [arr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]);
```

Both will return "1", which means "true", because arr is an object of the FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class, which inherits from NSArray.

**EDIT**
Let's see if I can explain it better:

```
arr1 = [[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet alloc] init];
arr2 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Both objects, arr1 and arr2, are created with the same method, which is defined in the class NSArray. However, in the first case the class which is being called is FlyNetArrayOfDataSet and in the second case is NSArray. Thus, `arr1` will be an object of class FlyNetArrayOfDataSet, while `arr2` will be of class NSArray.

The difference can be seen in this code:

```
NSLog(@"%d %d",
    [arr1 isKindOfClass:[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class]]
    [arr1 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
);
NSLog(@"%d %d",
    [arr2 isKindOfClass:[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class]]
    [arr2 isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
);
```

The output of this code is:

```
1 1 ( = true true)
0 1 ( = false true)
```

Comment: Depends on how NSArray creates the object in the `arrayWithObject` method!

Comment: This has always worked for me, at least with classes in system frameworks. He looked already confused enough to bother him with these edge cases, not important when working with Foundation classes :)

Comment: This will actually not work. You would have to override `initWithObjects:count:` because `arrayWithObject:` calls it and it's only defined for the abstract class (`NSArray` will throw an exception). Being a class cluster, it's usually a bad idea to subclass `NSArray` anyway, especially for a beginner.

Comment: Sure, I agree... But maybe you should add a note on this in your answer, as it's already well detailed. Also tell him to use NSStringFromClass, when in doubt, to debug the real class of the object... : )

Comment: omz, you are right. I'm trying to see if I can use a different method that will not have this issue.

Comment: I think I fixed it, in the second part. I used +alloc and -init, so now the code is working as I described. Thanks @omz.

Answer (score 0):

that's because `FlyNetArrayOfDataSet` is a `SoapArray` and `SoapArray` is *not* a `FlyNetArrayOfDataSet`.

if `datasets` were an instance of `SoapArray`, you will see "Soap" in the following example:

```
- (SoapRequest*)addFlyData:(id)target
                    action:(SEL)action
                 sessionid:(int)sessionid
                  datasets:(FlyNetArrayOfDataSet*)datasets
{
    if ([datasets isKindOfClass:[FlyNetArrayOfDataSet class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Fly");
    }
    else if ([datasets isKindOfClass:[SoapArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Soap");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"???");
    }
}
```

it's possible that an instance of `SoapArray` is also `FlyNetArrayOfDataSet`. the other possibilities are:

- a `SoapArray`
- subclass other than `FlyNetArrayOfDataSet`.

Comment: Please see EDIT2 of my question

Comment: try `SoapArray* a = [self array];`